# Memory leak when initializing @ObservedObject inside View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `ViewModel` class that is an `ObservableObject` and I initialize it when initializing its corresponding view. It seems that if I have any bindings to the `ViewModel` inside the view, the `ViewModel` is leaked.

For example, if I show said view inside a sheet, every time I present the sheet, a new reference is allocated and it does not get deallocated when the sheet is dismissed. The reference count keeps growing as many times I present the sheet.

Am I missing something, or is the `@ObservedObject` property wrapper not supposed to be used this way?

This is a simple example that exhibits the issue. The `deinit` function is never called for the `ViewModel`

```
struct NewContactView: View {

    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

        @Published var firstName = ""
        @Published var lastName = ""
        @Published var email = ""
        @Published var phoneNumber = ""

        init() {
            print("INIT")
        }

        deinit {
            print("DEINIT")
        }

    }

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var didCreateNewContact: (Contact) -> Void = { _ in }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Names")) {
                    TextField("First Name", text: $viewModel.firstName)
                    TextField("Last Name", text: $viewModel.lastName)
                }

                Section(header: Text("Details")) {
                    TextField("Email", text: $viewModel.email)
                    TextField("Phone Number", text: $viewModel.phoneNumber)
                }

                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Save")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit: Added code that presents the sheet**

```
struct ContactsListView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var contactStore: ContactStore

    @State private var isCreatingNewContact = false

    var body: some View {

            List(contactStore.contacts) { contact in
                ContactListItem(contact: contact)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { self.isCreatingNewContact = true }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            })


            .sheet(isPresented: $isCreatingNewContact) {
                NewContactView(didCreateNewContact: self.createNewContactHandler)
        }
    }


    private func createNewContactHandler(_ contact: Contact) {
        contactStore.contacts.append(contact)
        isCreatingNewContact = false
    }

}
```

**Edit 2: Memory Graph Screenshots**

[image: Memory graph]

**Edit 3: Weirdly enough, replacing the Form view with a VStack gets rid of the leak. If I use a List view instead of the VStack, the leak comes back.**

Comment: I could not get more than one INIT in output with presented code, even with added sheet to form. But that one INIT is expected, because you create instance of ViewModel during NewContactView initialization. And there is no DEINIT because view is presented. Please update with real demo of the issue.

Comment: @Asperi I did not include the code that shows the sheet for brevity. My apologies. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use @StateObject so it will init only once, for iOS 14

Never do this: @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel(), it will create viewmodels all the time.
You need to create this object at beginning of the app and pass it down where will not be recreated, or you can create in some view that is not updating as Dashboard depends on your app structure.

Comment: This is only availble in iOS 14+. It isn't available in iOS 13.

Comment: This is the correct answer. At the time of writing, however, StateObject did not exist  

Answer (score 1):

It does not look there is a leak. Here is my setup of views (added titles to screen for easy reference - code is after the explanation).

Navigating from

`User Setup`  -> `Contact Related` -> `Add Contact`

and going back all the way to main screen `User Setup` and then navigating to the next screen releases the previously created instance of the  view model.  Note: I added the unique id to the model which prints the id when the model is getting inited and deinited.

This leads me to believe that Models being observed are not deinited as soon as the view that is using it is getting released.  Swift runtime controls when the observable model should be released.  Also when I did the profiling for abandoned memory, I did not see any increase in the memory growth.  Also when the previously instance of the view model is getting released, there is a dip in the memory which proves the point that it is getting deallocated at that moment.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
        VStack {
             NavigationLink(destination: ContactRelated() ) {
                 Text("Contact Related")
             }
             Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("User Setup")
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ContactRelated: View {
        
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
             NavigationLink(destination: NewContactView() ) {
                 Text("Add New Contact")
             }
             Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Contact")
    }
}
```

```swift
struct NewContactView: View {
    
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        
        var id = UUID()
        
        @Published var firstName = ""
        @Published var lastName = ""
        @Published var email = ""
        @Published var phoneNumber = ""
        
        init() {
            print(">>>init \(id)")
        }
        
        deinit {
            print(">>>deinit \(id)")
        }
        
    }
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    //var didCreateNewContact: (Contact) -> Void = { _ in }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            
            Section(header: Text("Names")) {
                TextField("First Name", text: $viewModel.firstName)
                TextField("Last Name", text: $viewModel.lastName)
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Details")) {
                TextField("Email", text: $viewModel.email)
                TextField("Phone Number", text: $viewModel.phoneNumber)
            }
            
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
    .navigationBarTitle("Add Contact")
        
    }
}
```

Generally I will not add the definition of the observable view model within the struct.

Comment: I modified my code to use `NavigationLink` instead of a `.sheet` and indeed it behaves like you are saying. However if you present the create contact view using a sheet, it never seems to deallocate any of the `ViewModel` instances. Please see my edit which has the sheet presentation code.

Comment: You mean the definition or the initialization? If it’s the definition, it’s just for name spacing purposes but there’s no need to define it nested inside the view. The initialization because this is a view model for this specific view so the view has a reference to its own view model.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug. Using ScrollView instead of a List worked for me.